# three.js skybox assigned to camera

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js, skybox

I'm trying to make skybox assigned to player camera.
When camera moves(also skybox moves with it), texture get stretched.
How to get rid of this?

Code:

```
var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );
textureCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
var shader = THREE.ShaderUtils.lib[ "cube" ];
shader.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;

cubematerial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
    uniforms: shader.uniforms,
    depthWrite: false,
    side: THREE.BackSide
});
skyBox = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1000,1000,1000), cubematerial);
camera.add(skyBox);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after digging into Three.js examples, I found a way how to do this. http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/15/lets-do-a-sky/ is outdated. A way used in examples is to add skybox into second scene with fixed camera, and render both scenes. Look at webgl_materials_cars.html example.

Also because I use 3rd person camera assigned to character, I must get world rotation from character camera to skybox camera. This can be done on render with:

```
function render(){
<...>
    skyboxCamera.rotation.setEulerFromRotationMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().extractRotation( camera.matrixWorld ), skyboxCamera.eulerOrder );
    renderer.render(skyboxScene, skyboxCamera);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
<...>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a closed question but I want to offer an alternative that does not require an additional scene, for future seekers:

1. start by reading and following this tutorial: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/15/lets-do-a-sky/
2. now create the following shader (I added it to three.js ShaderLib, but if you don't want to temper with three' source code add it outside):

   ```
   'skybox': {

   uniforms: { "tCube": { type: "t", value: null },
               "tFlip": { type: "f", value: -1 } },

   vertexShader: [

       "varying vec3 vWorldPosition;",

       THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_pars_vertex" ],

       "void main() {",

       "   vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
       "   vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;",

       "   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position + cameraPosition, 1.0 );",

           THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_vertex" ],

       "}"

   ].join("\n"),

   fragmentShader: [

       "uniform samplerCube tCube;",
       "uniform float tFlip;",

       "varying vec3 vWorldPosition;",

       THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_pars_fragment" ],

       "void main() {",

       "   gl_FragColor = textureCube( tCube, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPosition.x, vWorldPosition.yz ) );",

           THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_fragment" ],

       "}"

   ].join("\n")
   ```

   },
3. create your skybox like this:

   ```
       // urls is a list of textures to use
   var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls); 
   cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat; 

   var shader = THREE.ShaderLib['skybox']; // init the skybox shader we created above
   shader.uniforms['tCube'].value = cubemap; // apply textures to shader

   // create shader material
   var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
     fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
     vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
     uniforms: shader.uniforms,
     depthWrite: false,
     side: THREE.BackSide
   });

   // create skybox mesh
   var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
     new THREE.CubeGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000),
     skyBoxMaterial
   );

           // THIS IS IMPORTANT! or the skybox will get culled after you move the camera too far..
   skybox.frustumCulled = false;
   ```